# Android Back Navigation ParentActivityName not working

Tags: android

i tried using this tutorial on how to provide a back navigation as in this code

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

```
 <activity android:name=".controller.general.AccountPickerScreen"
              android:parentActivityName="ph.edu.upm.agila.extendthelife.controller.general.LogInScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ph.edu.upm.agila.extendthelife.controller.general.AccountPickerScreen" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I already specificied the parentActivityName but whenever I press the back button the app exits? any solutions?

tried this

```
public void onBackPressed() {
     Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(AccountPickerScreen.this);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

it does work however i want to know if it is the right way of doing it? 
what does finish() do exactly

Comment: finish will destroy the current activity..

Comment: ^ there is nothing wrong with what I did? I used to solution provided by isuPatches

Comment: yeah try to remove to finish() because NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent will also execute finish() means finish() will be executed twice and might close AccountPickscreen as well and startActivity(intent) is not needed. NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent  will do all work for you

Comment: it doesnt return anymore when I removed startActivity(intent)

Comment: sorry mymistake your should not remove neither of them

Answer (score 2):

You may need to override the onBack for the activity and use NavUtils to accomplish what you want with a line like:

```
Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(AccountPickerScreen.this);
```

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: From your updated example and the comments below it it seems like you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

for api level below 16 try adding

```
<meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="fully qualified path to Activity Class Name" />
```

in activity tag in androidmanifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".controller.general.AccountPickerScreen">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="ph.edu.upm.agila.extendthelife.controller.general.AccountPickerScreen" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="ph.edu.upm.agila.extendthelife.controller.general.LogInScreen" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

override onBackPressed with `

```
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where the parent button worked on some activities but not others.

The problem was my onOptionsItemSelected function. It was returning true by default, which blocked the call from completing. You should call super.onOptionsItemSelected(item).

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html